# Is it acceptable for professors to plagiarise material for an academic textbook?

Tags: ethics, plagiarism

I know a professor who has recently written two books which are used as textbooks/academic books. However, I spotted a pretty recurrent pattern of plagiarism. They copy sentences and sometimes paragraphs up to several hundred words from Wikipedia, other articles, books, reports without referring to that work through both of the books. Often when they do copy, they include the references they copy (e.g. they copy A which refers to B and C), and they keep the references to A and B.

Is this in any way considered common practice? I obviously think not, but I am interested to ask whether I am simply too draconian in this regard.

Comment: No, this is not acceptable. Textbooks are definitely works in which attribution of other people's work is expected and required.

Comment: Plagiarism is plagiarism and as such not acceptable. In any publication.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know this is the case, and I was only really looking for confirmation of it. I'm just disappointed knowing this is a reputed Professor and he will be protected if I ever did anything with this

Comment: If you can report it anonymously to the university, e.g. in a physical letter without name and return address, using neutral language and showing evidence, you have at least done what you can with no risks to yourself. You could ask your friends to do the same. Then at least your conscience would be clear.

Comment: Once I was accused of copying from Wikipedia in an answer I posted to math(dot)stackexchange(dot)com, when in fact I had written the Wikipedia article myself. Might that have happened in the case of this professor?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry to say it's definitely not the case.

Comment: By textbook do you mean something they're taking to a publisher to sell? Or do you mean internal lecture notes? And if so, what is the level of the course?

Answer (score 6):

Replicating large portions of material from other books without permission; copying major portions of published work without citation -- this *is* blatantly plagiarism at all angles. This is downright unacceptable unethical practice.

Comment: The question was really: Is plagiarism _acceptable_ in this situation?